# Adding data files to tempdb database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. Size of data file of tempdb database is about 800 MB. I want to Know:
Is it a good idea to add another data file to database to decrease latch contention? Does it help to improve my SQL instant's performance?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/tempdb-data-files/

Comment: You might also want to consider upgrading your sql server. 2014 end of life was 3 years ago. It only has two years of extended support left.